# Remove a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code currently in one of my websites,

```
$("a.navlink").click(function (ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                var id = $(this).attr("id")
                if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                    alert(id);
                    $(id).remove("<div id="+ id +"/>");
                }
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
               var url = $(this).attr("href");
                $.ajax ({
                    url: "index.php/home/category",
                    type: "GET",
                    success : function (html) {
                //alert("Success");
                        $("#accordion").append($("<div id="+ id +"/>").append(html)
                        );
                    }
                });
            });
```

Essentially what is does it gets the ID from the click nav and gets some data from the database and then places that data in a div that is uniquely named with the ID of the click element.  What I want to know is how could then remove the div element that is created on the fly, as you can see from my code I have given it try.

Comment: There are a couple points I'm confused about logically here though beyond your problem with the remove() function. You said it's specific to the ID, but yet it's always calling the same URL in the ajax call. Also, you're appending a DIV with an ID that matches the element that's just been clicked on. (creating the same ID twice) Without seeing more, I can't completely speculate on what you're trying to accomplish. It's just a couple of tweaks, but it's not quite right.

Comment: Basically how it works is there database and codeigniter behind all of this, the menu is created dynamically with PHP and is given and ID, the ID is passed to the javascript and on the click of a link the URI is gathered by the url described and a query is fired of the to the database, the rsults are return and printed in a div that is ID'd by the ID that is on the link that was oriningally cliced I realise this is not validating and it will be changed to classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have another problem with your code.  You are attempting to give the DIV the same ID as the link.  IDs need to be unique so this results in invalid HTML.  Try prepending "div_" to the link's id, then use:

```
 $('#div_' + id).remove();
```

resulting in:

```
$("a.navlink").click(function (ev) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        alert(id);
        $('#div_' + id).remove();
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax ({
        url: "index.php/home/category",
        type: "GET",
        success : function (html) {
            //alert("Success");
            $("#accordion").append($("<div id='div_"+ id +"'/>").append(html));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
   $(this).remove();
}
```

Is all you need!

Comment: isnt this is representation of the link rather than the div?

Comment: Sure, and that's what you're getting the ID of according to this code. (see my comment to your main question) If you want the ID of a child DIV, then you need to do something different in your code.

Comment: i get the ID of (this) but only so I can assign it as class(was an id) to the div that is appended to #accordion